# How to plot in pandas - Different x and different y axis in a same plot

Tags: pandas, plot

I want to plot different values of x and y-axis from different CSVs into a simple plot.

csv1:

```
Time    Buff
1         5 
2        10 
3        15
```

csv2:

```
Time1  Buff1
2       3 
4       6 
5       9
```

I have 5 different CSVs. I tried plotting to concatenate the dataframes into a single frame and plot it. But I was able to plot with only one x-axis:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('csv1.txt)
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv2.txt) 
join = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1) 
join.plot(x='Time', y=['Buff', 'Buff1'], kind='line')
join.plot(x='Time', y='Buff', x='Time1', y='Buff1') #doesn't work
```

I end up getting a plot with reference with only one x-axis (csv1). But how to plot both x and y column from the CSVs into the same plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can plot two dataframes in the same axis if you specify that axis with `ax=`.  Notice that I created the figure and axis using subplots before i plotted either of the dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f,ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[1,2,3],'Buff':[5,4,3]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time1':[2,3,4],'Buff1':[5,7,8]})
df.plot(x='Time',y='Buff',ax=ax)
df1.plot(x='Time1',y='Buff1',ax=ax)
```

Comment: cool! glad to hear it worked for you.  would you say this is an acceptable answer, then?

Comment: Finally did it!